# How to solve for $x$ in $2^x=5^{x+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, exponentiation

So I was looking through the homepage of Youtube when I came across [this](https://youtu.be/WL-npSEyVTo) video by  Blackpenredpen which asked for the value of $x$ in $$2^x=5^{x+2}$$which I thought that I would be able to solve. Here is my attempt at solving the aforementioned equation:$$2^x=5^{x+2}$$$$x\ln2=(x+2)\ln5$$$$x=\frac{(x+2)\ln5}{\ln2}$$$$\frac{x}{x+2}=\ln(5)-\ln(2)$$$$\frac{x}{\ln(5)-\ln(2)}=x+2$$$$\frac{x}{\ln(5)=\ln(2)}-2=x$$$$\frac{\ln(5)-\ln(2)}{x}-0.5=\frac{1}{x}$$$$\ln(5)-\ln(2)-0.5x=1$$$$\ln(5)-\ln(2)=0.5x+1$$$$\ln(5)-\ln(2)-1=0.5x$$$$2\ln(5)-2\ln(2)-2=x$$$$\mathbf{\text{My question}}$$

---

Is the solution that I arrived at correct, or what could I do to attain the correct solution or attain it more easily?

Comment: Not correct: $$\frac{x}{\ln(5)-\ln(2)}-2=x $$ deos not imply $$\frac{\ln(5)-\ln(2)}{x}-0.5=\frac{1}{x} $$

Comment: It's same with $ \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^x=25$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is not correct.
The correct answer proceeds as follow:
$$ 2^x=5^{x+2}$$
$$x\ln2=(x+2)\ln5$$
$$x\ln2=x\ln5+2\ln5$$
$$x\ln2-x\ln5=\ln25$$
$$x(\ln2-\ln5)=\ln25$$
$$x=\frac{\ln25}{\ln2-\ln5}$$
$$x =\frac{\ln 25}{\ln \frac 25}$$

Comment: Would this imply that for any $a^x=b^{x+c}$, $x=\dfrac{\ln\left(b^c\right)}{\ln\left(\dfrac ab\right)}$?

Comment: Yes, the result is correct

Answer (score 3):

As noticed there is an issue with an intermediate step, more easily we can proceed as follows

$$2^x=5^{x+2} \iff 2^x=5^x\cdot5^2 \iff  \left(\frac25\right)^x=25 \iff x\ln \frac 25 =\ln 25 \iff x =\frac{\ln 25}{\ln \frac 25}$$

Comment: Difference is 31 sec.

Answer (score 1):

###### Is your solution correct?

Unfortunately not. You can check it by entering the result in the original equation. You made a mistake from
$$\frac{x}{\ln(5)-\ln(2)}-2=x$$
to
$$\frac{\ln(5)-\ln(2)}{x}-0.5=\frac{1}{x}$$

###### How to attain a solution more easily?

Try to get rid of the parentheses in
$$x\ln 2 = (x+2)\ln 5$$

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem between your line 6 and 7. Here's a faster way.
$$2^x=5^{x+2}\iff x\ln(2)=(x+2)\ln(5)\iff x\ln(2)-x\ln(5)=2\ln(5)\iff x=\frac{2\ln(5)}{\ln(2)-\ln(5)}=-\frac{2\ln(5)}{\ln(\frac52)}$$